# Android thread XML reader method

Tags: android, xml, multithreading

How can I thread method readRss() so that if the internet connection is slow it doesnt slow down the rest of the app?

```
package com.noah.rss;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class AndroidRssReader extends ListActivity {

     private RSSFeed myRssFeed = null;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
         readRss();
     }

     public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> {

      public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<RSSItem> list) {
          super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            View row = convertView;

            if (row == null) {
               LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
               row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            }

            TextView listTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listtitle);
            listTitle.setText(myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getTitle());
            TextView listPubdate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.listpubdate);
            listPubdate.setText(myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getPubdate());

            if (position % 2 == 0) {
                listTitle.setBackgroundColor(0xff101010);
                listPubdate.setBackgroundColor(0xff101010);
            } else {
                listTitle.setBackgroundColor(0xff080808);
                listPubdate.setBackgroundColor(0xff080808);
            }
            return row;
      }

      private void readRss() {
          try {
              URL rssUrl = new URL("http://www.gov.hk/en/about/rss/govhkrss.data.xml");
              SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
              SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
              XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
              RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
              myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
              InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
              myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

              myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();

          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (SAXException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

          if (myRssFeed != null) {
               TextView feedTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
               TextView feedDescribtion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feeddescribtion);
               TextView feedPubdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedpubdate);
               TextView feedLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.feedlink);
               feedTitle.setText(myRssFeed.getTitle());
               feedDescribtion.setText(myRssFeed.getDescription());
               feedPubdate.setText(myRssFeed.getPubdate());
               feedLink.setText(myRssFeed.getLink());

               MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, R.layout.row, myRssFeed.getList());
               setListAdapter(adapter);
          }
     }

     @Override
     protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
         Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowDetails.class);
         Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
         bundle.putString("keyTitle", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getTitle());
         bundle.putString("keyDescription", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getDescription());
         bundle.putString("keyLink", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getLink());
         bundle.putString("keyPubdate", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getPubdate());
         intent.putExtras(bundle);
         startActivity(intent);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Reload");
         return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case (0):
              Toast.makeText(this, "Reading News, Please wait.",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              readRss();
              break;
          default:
              break;
         }
         return true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), That'll create a separate thread for parsing, so it wont consume your UI Thread. :)

Here's an [Informative](http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7746) Sample, Good luck!

Comment: Why is it that I get an error when I try:
 protected Thread initBkgdThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
  readRss();
  
  }
  });

Comment: @user,Well, your `readRss` function contains parts of code that modify the UI Components (TextViews), that is not allowed, UI Components can only be modified from the UI Thread....You may use `runOnUiThread` or a `Handler` to run `Runnables` in the UI Thread....but make sure the XML processing is done in the Non-UI Thread....

Comment: Thanks stOle, it worked, I creaed a Rannable:private Runnable mUpdateListTask = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
   readRss();
   displayRss();
   }
  };